# User click on image to download public file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like a user of my rails app to be able to click on a link 'download' and that they will then download a png file I have placed in my public folder. ('tool.png')

At the moment I have the incorrect...

```
<%= link_to "download", '/tool.png', :action => 'download' %>
```

I have created a download action in the controller:

```
def download
    send_file '/tool.png', :type=>"application/png", :x_sendfile=>true
end
```

What is happening here is that when a user clicks on the 'download' link it opens tool.png in its own window, rather than actually downloading the file.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: if your image is in the public folder and your rails application/webserver is set up to serve those files then you can simply link to them with `link_to 'download the image', 'tool.png'`

Comment: thanks - that doesn't download it though, it just seems to open the png in a new browser window?

Comment: ah, so you want to send it as an attachement. then you need to send_file it from a controller-action in your rails applicaton.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### HTML 5

For `HTML5` it's actually very simple. You don't need a special controller action.

```
<%= link_to "download", '/tool.png', :download => 'filename' %>
# 'filename' specifies the new name for the downloaded file
```

*Note: [check the docs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) to see what browsers are supported*

### < HTML 5

If you want to support all browsers you must use the `download action` which you setup. The only thing missing is setting up the correct `route`.

**routes.rb**

```
get '/download_pdf', "controller_name#download", :as => :download_pdf
```

then link your HTML to the correct path, which will call the `download action` and send the file.

```
<%= link_to "download", :download_pdf_path
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

```
<%= link_to "download", '/download', :action => 'download' %>
```

not

```
<%= link_to "download", '/tool.png', :action => 'download' %>
```

Where `"/download"` is the rails `route` which need to be specified in routing file.

since in your case your are not actually hitting the controller, you are just accessing `http://host/tool.png`. Check your development logs for more info, you will see no logs since  request is not directly served by rails but with other case you will see them.